# Removing scattered points from matplotlib after awhile

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to scatter some streaming points on a plot. I am using an interactive plot suing plt.scatter() from matplotlib package in python. Every 5 second I will scatter the points. I dont need to keep all the points and accumulate them, but I need to keep the past 20 seconds points. Any help?

```
def data_plotting(q):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    plt.ion() # Interactive mode
    fig.show()
    colors = plt.get_cmap('jet')(np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, clusterNum))

    while True:
        if q.empty():
            time.sleep(5)

        else:
            obj=q.get() # (DenseVector([6.7456, 7.7456]), 0)
            d=[x[0] for x in obj]
            c=[x[1] for x in obj]
            data = np.array(d)
            pcolor=np.array(c)

            try:

                plt.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1],  marker='o', alpha = 0.5,color=colors[pcolor])
                plt.pause(0.0001)
                plt.draw()
                time.sleep(5)
            except IndexError: # Empty array
                pass
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is assign a datetime field to each of your points. After each iteration, you can check what points are past 20s old and then delete them from your data set.